# Receive parameters via POST and use them to create an object in PHP, then JSON serialize the object

Tags: php, json, class, post, parameters

**background:**

I am receiving transaction initialization parameters via POST for a payment service. Then I need to use those parameters to create a 'Deposit' object in PHP and then JSON serializes the deposited object and stores JSON to a variable.

I am trying to achieve that with the following code:

**code:**

```
//get parameters by POST and add to Deposit class
$user_id = echo $_POST["user"];
$tradingaccount_id = echo $_POST["trading_account"];
$fundprocessor_id = echo $_POST["func_processor"];
$paymentgateway_type = echo $_POST["payment_gateway_type"];
$paymentgateway_id = echo $_POST["payment_gateway_id"];
$amount = echo $_POST["deposit_amount"];
$client_ip = echo $_POST["user_ip"];

//Deposit class
var deposit = new Deposit 
{ 
UserId = echo $user_id, 
TradingAccountId = new Guid(echo $tradingaccount_id), 
FundProcessorId = int (echo $fundprocessor_id), 
PaymentGatewayId = echo $paymentgateway_id, 
Amount = echo $amount, 
ClientIp = echo $client_ip 

//serialize data to JSON
function getJsonData(){
    $var = get_object_vars($this);
    foreach ($var as &$value) {
        if (is_object($value) && method_exists($value,'getJsonData')) {
            $value = $value->getJsonData();
        }
    }
    return $var;
}

};
```

**Question:**

Is the above the correct way to do this?
Will $var variable contain the JSON serialized object?

Comment: Please read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) on how variables are declaread.

Comment: @hungrykoala , you mean I should change the way variables are declared inside the 'Deposit' class? Thanks

Comment: you don't need to echo them when you're assigning variables. `$user_id = $_POST["user"];`

Comment: I see, so I shouldn't use echo inside the class too, right?

Answer (score 0):

If your `Deposit` class won't be implementing any additional logic, you can take a simpler approach:

```
  $deposit = [];

  $deposit['UserId'] = $_POST["user"];
  $deposit['TradingAccountId'] = new Guid($_POST["trading_account"]);
  $deposit['FundProcessorId'] = intval($_POST["func_processor"]);
  $deposit['PaymentGatewayId'] = $_POST["payment_gateway_id"];
  $deposit['Amount'] = $_POST["deposit_amount"];
  $deposit['ClientIp'] = $_POST["user_ip"];

  $json = json_encode($deposit);
```

Otherwise you should implement [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php) in your class.